# How to implement a Mutex in Python when using Gtk with PyGTK

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, mutex

I have an application that starts several threads using

`gobject.timeout_add(delay, function)`

Now in my function I want to test and set on some variable, e.g.

`def function(self):

    if flag == True:
        flag = False
        doSomething()`

Now to make this threadsafe, I would have to lock the function using some mutex lock.
Is this possible with Gtk? Or can I use the Python `Lock` objects from `threading`?

Comment: You can just use `threading.Lock` for a simple mutex implementation.

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but I believe since GLib's mutex functions aren't wrapped in Python, you should just use `threading`.

Comment: I have deleted my answer and i will replace it with this comment: before digging your self in gtk threading i invite you to read this two docs , i hope they can more helpful : http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Threads.html, http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness.html.

Comment: Note that you should **not** use the Python 2.x [`mutex`](http://docs.python.org/library/mutex.html) module. [It's not thread-safe.](http://bugs.python.org/issue1746071).  (That's true.  Honestly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `gobject.timeout_add(delay, function)` and `gobject.idle_add(function)` are safe to use. I tried it using

```
for i in range(X):
    gobject.idle_add(workerFunction)
```

and found out that there are NEVER two worker threads executing at the same time. That means it seems like the function calls performed by the `gobject.timeout_add(delay, function)` and `gobject.idle_add(function)` are atomic in the sense that they are executed always strictly one after another. So, not even the simple check posted in the question is necessary.

In fact I could not get any race condition to manifest no matter what I did. So no additional locking mechanism is required.

Comment: Is it written somewhere that it is _guaranteed_ that there will be no race condition? Then no additional locking mechanism is required. Otherwise, you are just asking for trouble, because your code will suddenly break on another machine, or on the same machine some time in the future when the internal implementation of `idle_add` changes.

Comment: Well I have not found the details in the documentation yet. But I am guessing that the function is not really creating a new thread, but just telling the gtk main loop to call the function when there is nothing else to do. So it is really just useful for very small and short function calls, otherwise the GUI gets unresponsive.